# Selenium (Python): No such driver version 115.0.5790.114 for mac-arm64

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Selenium was working until this morning that this error occured:

```
No such driver version 115.0.5790.114 for mac-arm64
```

I've been searching for answers but none was able to solve this problem.

Here's my code to initialize driver:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True 
    options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
    chrome_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    chrome_service = Service(chrome_path)
    driver = Chrome(options=options, service=chrome_service)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Here's the versions that I used:

```
webdriver-manager==3.9.1
selenium==4.10.0
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your browser got updated to newer version. Could you please check the version of your browser and downgrade it to the version where your webdriver version supports. If possible disable automatic update of browser so that this issue will not arise in future(Note : You can always update whenever there is a supportable driver version ).

Comment: Thank you! I have also downgraded my webdriver-manager to 3.8.6, which is what I was using before. The 3.9.1 version kept giving me errors.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium Manager is now fully included with `selenium` `4.10.0`, so you no longer need to use `webdriver-manager`/`ChromeDriverManager`. This is all you need now:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.

---

If you're wondering why you're now seeing this error for `ChromeDriverManager`, it's because https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114 due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).